# How can two or more developers work on a same app?

Tags: app-development

I would like to have two or more developers working on a same app, how can they share app objects and customization with other developer accounts.

Comment: What have you looked at so far?

Comment: i already looked for this in developer.force.com and could not find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option for achieving concurrent development with Salesforce is to use an IDE via the Metadata API. For example, download and use the Force.com IDE (or get Sublime Text and the MavensMate plugin).

This [Force.com Eclipse](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation) article talks you nicely through getting the Force.com IDE installed you can find out about developing in it, and connecting up a project on [this wiki article](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force_IDE). Basically you are going to "download" local copies of all your Apex Classes, Pages, and the Metadata representing your Objects/Workflows etc.etc. - then, as you work, the IDE will monitor changes on the "server" (which is your Salesforce org) and warn if the file has been changed by someone else, allowing you to do a "diff" or compare to submit only the appropriate changes.

[image]

If clean, saves are reflected directly on your DE or Sandbox for review and testing.

It's not easy, and communication is the key to make sure you are not destroying each others work. Being aware of what is being worked on and what you should commit is important.

Obviously a Developer Edition gives you two user licences, which I suggest different developers use, and Sandboxes come with as many licences as they are Sandboxed for in Production. As tempting as password sharing is among developers, it makes for a useless audit trail of who changed what and why.

There is plenty of reference material on the internet about concurrent development, and even loads on doing so with Salesforce. A good Google should augment this answer massively.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep each developer in their own sandbox or developer org and use Git to manage your source. Each developer can work on branches independently and then merge their changes when they are ready. This prevents two people from saving over the other's work. I recently wrote a [blog post](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/01/06/team-development-on-force-com/) outlining how to work in a team environment.

Comment: Using an external source management tool (such as Git) in conjunction with the IDEs on separate Sandboxes, with a push to a staging Org is definitely a good way to work with multiple developers if you have the infrastructure/skills. Especially useful for organising UAT and multi-track/branch developing.